# Elasticsearch for python - Calls not blocking correctly

Tags: python, elasticsearch, synchronization

I'm trying to write unittests for my own Elasticsearch client. It uses the client from `elasticsearch-py`.

Most of my tests are fine, but when running a test on my own `search()` function (which uses the `search()` function from `Elasticsearch` client) I get very random behaviour. This is the way my test is implemented:

```py
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.es = ESClient(host="localhost")
        self.es_acc = ESClient()
        self.connection_res = (False, {})

        self.t = self.es_acc.get_connection_status(self._callback)
        self.t.join()

        # Create test index and index some documents
        self.es.create_index(self.TEST_INDEX)
        names = ["Gregor", "Alice", "Per Svensson", "Mats Hermelin", "Mamma Mia"
            , "Eva Dahlgren", "Per Morberg", "Maja Larsson", "Ola Salo", "Magrecievic Holagrostokovic"]
        self.num_docs = len(names)
        self.payload = []
        random.seed(123)

        for i, name in enumerate(names):
            n = name.split(" ")
            fname = n[0]
            lname = n[1] if len(n) > 1 else n[0]

            self.payload.append({"name": {"first": fname, "last": lname}, "age": random.randint(-100, 100),
                                 "timestamp": datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1 * i)})

        self.es.upload(self.TEST_INDEX, self.payload, ids=list(range(len(names))))

    def test_search(self):
        # Test getting docs based on ids
        ids = ["1", "4", "9"]
        status, hits = self.es.search(self.TEST_INDEX, ids=ids) # Breakpoint
        docs = hits["hits"]["hits"]
        self.assertTrue(status, "Status not correct for search!")
        returned_ids = [d["_id"] for d in docs]
        names = [d["_source"]["name"] for d in docs]
        self.assertListEqual(sorted(returned_ids), ids, "Returned ids from search not correct!")
        self.assertListEqual(names, [self.payload[i]["name"] for i in [1, 4, 9]], "Returned source from search not correct!")
```

In `setUp()` I'm just uploading a few documents to test on, so there should always be 10 documents to test on. Below is an excerpt from my `search()` function.

```py
        if ids:
            try:
                q = Query().ids(ids).compile_and_get()
                res = self.es.search(index=index, body=q)
                print(res)
                return True, res
            except exceptions.ElasticsearchException as e:
                self._handle_elastic_exceptions("search", e, index=index)
                return False, {}
```

I've implemented `Query`. Anyway, when I just run the test, I **ALMOST** always get 0 hits. But if I debug the application, with a breakpoint in `test_search()` on the row where I make the call to `search()` and step, everything works fine. If I put it just one line below, I get 0 hits again. What is going on? Why is it not blocking correctly?

Comment: It seems like I found my solution! 

1. I did not understand that `setUp`was called on every test method. This was actually not the problem however.
2. The problem is that for some tests, uploading documents simply took to much time (which was done in `setUp`) and so when the test started, the documents did not exist yet! Solution: add `sleep(1)` to the end of `setUp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I found my solution!

1. I did not understand that `setUp` was called on every test method. This was actually not the problem however.
2. The problem is that for some tests, uploading documents simply took to much time (which was done in `setUp`) and so when the test started, the documents did not exist yet! Solution: add `sleep(1)` to the end of `setUp`.

Comment: there should be a better solution than that. I mean you will have the same problem if takes more than 1s.